# Where should I add c.InlineBackend.rc = {} in IPython to use my own matplotlib rc

Tags: python, matplotlib, ipython

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16905028/why-is-matplotlib-plot-produced-from-ipython-notebook-slightly-different-from-te) and [this email archive](http://mail.scipy.org/pipermail/ipython-dev/2013-May/011509.html), it seems that I should use the command

```
c.InlineBackend.rc = {}
```

In my IPython config file to let IPython use my own matplotlib rcParams. However, I tried to add it in the .ipython/profile_default/startup/my_startup_file.py, it didn't work. I guess I added it to the wrong file. May I ask which one is the file I should add this line in?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

```
.ipython/profile_default/ipython_config.py
```

Although for other users, the file might be located at:

```
.config/ipython/profile_default/ipython_config.py
```

If the config file doesn't exist, run this command to create it:

```
ipython profile create
```

This is a config file, which sets config values for IPython, whereas files in `.../startup/` are startup files, which are run in the interactive namespace while IPython is starting, so you can do things like imports whenever IPython starts.