# Ipython+matplotlib produces very different-sized figures running directly or from script

Tags: python, matplotlib, ipython

I'm having a strange issue with ipython and matplotlib, where figure sizes are changing depending on if I run code directly in command line or from a script with %run. If I run:

```
In [1]: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
In [2]: plt.ion()                                                                                        
In [3]: plt.figure()
```

I get as output:

```
Out[3]: <Figure size 640x480 with 0 Axes>
```

(Which looks "the right size" for my screen).

However, if I put the same three lines into a script, and call it via `%run`, the output is

```
Out[2]: <Figure size 1280x960 with 0 Axes>
```

And for completeness, if I first import matplotlib and open a figure in command line, then run the script, all figures are 640x480! I checked that it's calling the same version of matplotlib in both cases (3.1.1). I also looked at the rc parameters (as suggested in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16905028/why-is-matplotlib-plot-produced-from-ipython-notebook-slightly-different-from-te>), the figsize and dpi are identical.

Any ideas as to what's going on?

I'm using IPython 7.8.0, Python 3.7.4 (from an Anaconda3 install), on centOS 7.7.1908.